# Сохранение данных в консольном приложении(.NET Framework) C#

Tags: c#, .net

Есть приложение которое присваивает введенные значения нужным переменным. Как организовать сохранение этих значений,что бы при новом  открытии приложения я мог вывести их значения(данные прошлой сессии) в консоли?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("число 1");
        int x1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("число 2");
        int x2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());                                
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
}
```

Comment: Например, записать в файл. При запуске - считать обратно.

Comment: @CrazyElf Буду благодарен если направите на статью с этой темой или поможете с написанием кода.

Comment: Просто почитайте про чтение и запись файлов в C#. Вам будет достаточно текстового файла, запишите туда свои числа, каждое в отдельной строке. Читайте из файла тоже как строки, а потом конвертируйте их в int так же как вы делаете в своём коде в вопросе.

Answer (score -1):

Сохранение в XML файл

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp14
{
    //Класс для хранения данных программы
    public class ProgramData
    {
        public int Value1 { get; set; }
        public int Value2 { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() => $"{Value1}, {Value2}";
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static readonly XmlSerializer _xmlSerializer =
                                    new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProgramData));
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var file = @"D:\programdata.xml";

            var progData = GetProgramData(file);

            Console.WriteLine(progData);
            Console.WriteLine(new string('=', 20));

            SetNewValues(progData);
            Console.WriteLine(progData);
            SaveProgData(progData, file);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Чтение из файла значений и создание экземпляра ProgramData
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file">путь к файлу</param>
        /// <returns>экземпляр ProgramData</returns>
        private static ProgramData GetProgramData(string file)
        {
            ProgramData progData = new ProgramData();
            if (File.Exists(file))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(file))
                    {
                        progData = (ProgramData)_xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fs);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            return progData;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Присваивание новых значений
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="progData">экземпляр ProgramData</param>
        private static void SetNewValues(ProgramData progData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("число 1");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int value1))
            {
                progData.Value1 = value1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("число 2");
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int value2))
            {
                progData.Value2 = value2;
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Сохранение в файл экземпляра ProgramData
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="progData">экземпляр ProgramData</param>
        /// <param name="file">путь к файлу</param>
        private static void SaveProgData(ProgramData progData, string file)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(file))
                {
                    _xmlSerializer.Serialize(fs, progData);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```